# "window.frame.openDialog" not able select files in Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, macos, appjs

Using `window.frame.openDialog`, I am not able to select the files from the `Open` dialog box in `Mac OS X`. I could select the directory but not the files. Is there any way to select the files?

My code is:

```
window.frame.openDialog({
  type: 'open',
  title: 'Open...',
  multiSelect: false,
  acceptTypes: {
    'Images': ['*.hwc']
  },
  dirSelect: false,
  initialValue: '/'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In MAC it is not possible to select files using **window.frame.openDialog**, instead of you can search and select file using **fs.readFile**.